# Where "being" should be used?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning

I was reading newspaper and there was a sentence

> WFI Recently exempted the phogat sisters from the national camp **being held at lucknow**

I am not very sure about where we should use **being**. But i know that **being** is generally used in passive voice. So if we consider this as passive voice then it should be "national **camp was held at lucknow**"

> WFI Recently exempted the phogat sisters from the national camp **was held at lucknow**

Or i think we can also write first sentence without **being**

> WFI Recently exempted the phogat sisters from the national camp **held at lucknow**

can someone please explain where we should use **being** ?

Comment: The second version is definitely wrong.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. Do you disagree with where the quote had put the word "being"? Where would you rather place it?

Comment: -1 for not telling us where you got the article, and for misquoting the original by not capitalizing proper nouns. [Relevant reading](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source).